# Alternative when IN clause is inputed A LOT of values (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm using the IN clause to retrieve places that contains certain tags. For that I simply use

```
select .. FROM table WHERE tags IN (...)
```

For now the number of tags I provide in the IN clause is around 500) but soon (in the near future) number tags will probably jump off to easily over 5000 (maybe even more)

I would guess there is some kind of limition in both the size of the query AND in the number values in the IN clause (bonus question for curiosity what is this value?)

So my question is what is a good alternative query that would be future proof even if in the future I would be matching against let's say 10'000 tags ?

ps: I have looked around and see people mentioning "temporary table". I have never used those. How will they be used in my case? Will i need to create a temp table everytime I make a query ?

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: These tags, where do they come from?

Comment: Which language are you using? If your language's database driver supports arrays, you can use `... where tags in (select unnest(<array_parameter>)`

Comment: @Vérace their are coming from an external source

Comment: @Colin'tHart I use java (with JPA) I try to to everything in JPQL but if there is REALY the need to use some database related function I could use a nativeQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to speed up IN queries under PostgreSQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/ways-to-speed-up-in-queries-under-postgresql)

Comment: @Colin: Even simpler: `WHERE tags = ANY(<array_parameter>)`. Seems to cope just fine with a 500,000-element array (assuming `tags` is indexed, of course...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to join this to a `values` clause

```
with parms (tag) as (
  values ('tag1'), ('tag2'), ('tag3')
)
select t.*
from the_table t
  join params p on p.tag = t.tag;
```

Comment: Nice - using mostly MySQL, I sometimes forget the deadly handy WITH clause (or CTE). If only MySQL would get off its a** and implement it - but then MySQL might become a real competitor for Oracle! +1

Comment: @Vérace: MySQL is missing much more [modern SQL features](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) than just CTEs.

Comment: Don't I know. However, just as molecular biology/bioinformatics was taking off pre-2000, MySQL scooped up that niche (free, relatively easy to install for non-techie biology types (me excepted...)) fast on read-only data, so I'm stuck with! It's kinda ironic that the worst (in terms of features at least) open source db is also the most popular. PostgreSQL and Firebird **way** outstrip it in terms of features, yet here we are...

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. That is a very nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table using:

```
tablename

id  |   tags
----+----------
1   | tag1
2   | tag2
3   | tag3
```

And then do:

```
select .. FROM table WHERE tags IN (SELECT * FROM tablename)
```

Comment: For every query the list of tags is different, does that mean I need to create and drop the table for every query ?

Comment: Or you create a temporary table with these tags or you have to create and drop.

Comment: Right, With PostreSQL I know there is a CREATE TEMP TABLE .. DROP ON COMMIT. But because my tags are coming from an external source I will have to manually insert them ALL in the table everytime ?

Comment: "For every query the list of tags is different" - can't you use "SELECT .. FROM My_Table WHERE tags IN (SELECT * FROM My_Tag_Table WHERE My_Tag_Name LIKE 'xyz%')? I mean, use a WHERE clause to get the tags you want for a given query?

Comment: Where are the tags coming from? how are they coming?

Comment: @Vérace What is xyz%' ?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado doesn't really matter where they coming from really, let's just say I receive a fairly large amount of tags (that may or may not exist in my Tag table) and I need to retrieve all the place that contains these tags

Comment: I think that @a_horse_with_no_name has given you the solution you require.